# Compare two voltages and output the higher of those two

Tags: analog, comparator

From the LM35 output I get from 0V to 1.5V. There are 4 outputs like this.

How can I compare these values without using a micro-controller and forward the highest value of those 4.

I can't connect the sensor outputs, nor to make a sum.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To flesh out Andy's answer a bit you can do this with only 4 inexpensive and common components:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFcQOl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can add a buffer to Vout if necessary.

Comment: Probably a different diode would be necessary, since BAV70 has quite a large drop even in the 0.1-1 mA range.

Comment: @JanDorniak Maximum sensor voltage is 1.5V, add 0.6V to that and the LM324 can easily handle it. Remember, the diode is **inside** the feedback loop for the highest voltage.

Comment: Yeah, I missed the diode being inside the feedback loop, my bad.

Answer (score 3):

If you look up a circuit known as a precision rectifier (based around an op-amp and a couple of diodes), you will see that it forms the basis for what you want: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_rectifier). There is also a simpler version that might also suit what you require: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Op-Amp_Precision_Rectifier.svg).

So, if you have four inputs (as shown in your question), you will need 4 precision rectifier circuits and, each output can be joined to each other.

Basically, the precision rectifier that produces the highest voltage will win the day and get to produce its voltage at the output and reverse bias the three other circuits.

Comment: I'm interested in the advantages of the first over the second. The second is what I'd come up with "out of my head" if new to the concept: what doesthe first correct for? Low output impedence? Some exicitng non-linearity in the diodes?

Comment: Just following your link to answer my comment, the basic circuit goes open-loop and saturates on negative voltages which is obviously bad for a real-world op-amp.

Comment: @Dannie correct, the 2nd circuit goes into saturation and can be a problem if you want fast response times. Other than that, (for DC levels with no great expectation of speed), they behave the same.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT: To clarify for anyone downvoting, the original question read "And can not connect the sensor outputs, or to make a sum." It was since edited twice (not by the author) and is still is not very clear exactly what they meant... but just in case the OP was asking if they *could* make a sum of voltages, the answer is yes and this is described below.**

To **sum** the voltages, a [summing operational amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier_applications#Summing_amplifier) is used:

[image: Summing op-amp]

The output is negative, so requires (positive and negative) supply voltages.
Ex: +1.5V and +1V --> -2.5V out

To "invert" this back into a positive voltage, add an "[inverting amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier_applications#Inverting_amplifier)" after this with it's gain set to 1.00.  Then the output would be +2.5V.