# What happens if two linear optocouplers are paralleled, if their output voltages are different?

Tags: opto-isolator

If the outputs are connected, what voltage would be detected at the combined output? The higher voltage? Or, would the lower voltage device malfunction in some way? Hoping to see the highest voltage on the connected output.

Since they are optically isolated, i think it's not possible for one output to feed into the other output. Series diodes on the outputs are fine, if needed to prevent interaction.

I'm considering linear optocouplers. There would not be a load on the combined outputs. I think supplying a high-impedance input would be considered a no-load/low-load condition. This is a sensing application, not load-bearing.

Example part: a temperature-compensated device such as HCNR200
https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/HCNR200-HCNR201-High-Linearity-Analog-Optocouplers-DS

Comment: It depends on the output stage being used. What happens is the same as if you paralled the same transistor types used in the output stages.

Comment: @DKNguyen That sounds like current could feed into the lower-voltage device.

Comment: @johnywhy Indeed. And some transistor types can be current shared while others can't be.

Comment: @DKNguyen My goal isn't current-sharing, tho'. My goal is for the combined output to have the voltage of the higher voltage device. This is a sensing application, where i want to put multiple sensors on the same bus, such that the bus voltage will be whatever is the highest voltage connected to it.

Comment: That's probably not happening with a passive approach. Also, note that linear optocouplers require considerable circuitry around them to do their job since they require a negative feedback loop, which you have not shown in your schematic. You're probably better off just using a bunch of comparators and an analog mux.

Comment: This schematic seems to do it with diodes. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/615718/65001

Comment: @DKNguyen Diodes seems to work. http://tinyurl.com/ywok4wp8

Comment: Diodes screw up the signal though, depending on accurate you need it. Though I suppose ideal active diodes are an option to get around this.

Comment: @DKNguyen If you mean Vdrop, that's ok for my application, as long as i know it's there.

Comment: This is not an analog voltage isolator device, it is an error amp used specifically for power supply applications. Your schematic seems to be erroneous, but there are meaningful ways the outputs can be wired together; the phototransistors simply act as ordinary BJTs with a phantom base current applied (the photocurrent generated internally).

Comment: @TimWilliams Can you mention a meaningful way the outputs could be connected? What do you mean "not analog"? The BJT's operate in linear region, correct?

Comment: I don't know what your intent was, so I won't try and suggest something. But they can be wired any way normal BJTs can be wired. Series and parallel combinations, with a pull-up or -down resistor, might prove fruitful. But again, they aren't proportional isolators, and you can't do the thing you seem to want to do with them. (Or, you can, in the simulator, where devices match perfectly and have no drift or aging over temperature and time.)

Comment: @TimWilliams unclear. You dont know my intent, but i cant do it, but i can. As mentioned above, i want the bus to hold the highest voltage sensed. Why would i need perfectly matched devices? Assume i'm using a device similar to this HCNR200, which use two photodiodes to minimize nonlinearity and temperature drift. https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/HCNR200-HCNR201-High-Linearity-Analog-Optocouplers-DS

Comment: *"Why would i need perfectly matched devices?"* -- Good question; where in the datasheet could we find justification for this claim?  If we need to know the sensed voltage (across two isolation barriers), the gain had better be accurate for both. As it turns out, you will be hard pressed indeed to find a phototransistor type with CTR tighter than +/-50%. Should I assume this HCNR (and in a more representative circuit) as example now? If so, please edit your post to reflect what you're interested in.

Comment: @TimWilliams edited

Comment: Now, these are photodiode output devices. Do you still mean to ask what happens if they are paralleled? Or would you use one of the example circuits? (Your schematic seems to be obsolete now.) What accuracy of comparison is required, and is trimming acceptable?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, what happens if paralleled? A series diode is fine, if needed. I think my schematic was already just a rough approximation. I believe the circuit in the datasheet shows usage as feedback in a DC converter -- that's not my application. Just using the device as aa voltage sensor.

Comment: @johnywhy - Hi, While self-answers can be written, you wrote one using comments from another site member *without correct attribution*. That is not allowed & it has been deleted. || If someone has provided an answer in comments, it is a good idea to first ask them to write an answer. If they don't do so within a reasonable time (e.g. a day) or if they say they don't want to, then the approach [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252303) can be used to synthesize an answer - but their comments *must* be correctly attributed & other parts of the CC BY-SA 4.0 license *must* be followed.

Comment: (continued) Also, since any such self-answer is using someone else's material to solve the question, it should be set as "Community Wiki" to avoid claiming points for reposting *their* knowledge. FYI [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/695546) is an example of a "self-answer from someone else's comments" that I helped another site member to create, with appropriate attribution & links. If needed, I can help you to do this here, if that site member doesn't want to write an answer.

Comment: @SamGibson My answer employed an observation which i stated in my question, and in my own comment too. "That sounds like current could feed into the lower-voltage device." The other commenter didn't say that. . their comment didn't contain a complete answer.

Comment: @johnywhy - "*their comment didn't contain a complete answer*" Doesn't matter. You quoted 2 of their comments without attribution. "*My answer employed my own comment*" Yes, I saw that - it was the 2 copied comments from another user, without attribution, which is not allowed here. Specifically, you broke the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) by copying (or adapting) their material without attribution & other stipulations. Copying (or adapting) someone else's material (even if you also added your own) needs to be done correctly, if it's done at all.

Comment: @SamGibson Sure, i can attribute the other commenter. Are you saying that quoting my OWN comment is a violation? Where in SE policy does it say that comments, or answers for that matter, are protected by CC license?

Comment: @johnywhy - We should take this to a chatroom (which I'll setup later today, when I get out of a meeting) and then I can remove all these comments. The short answer to your licensing question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public#licensing) in the Terms Of Service linked at the bottom of the page. Regarding comments - hover over the date/time of a comment and it tells you which license applies. You'll see currently it's CC BY-SA 4.0 (earlier license versions applied many years ago).

Comment: @TimWilliams It seems nonlinearity, and the distinction about matched vs unmatched , aren't relevant to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since the optocoupler referenced is a photodiode output device (as observed in a comment by @TimWilliams), and not a transistor output device, we may consider parallel photodiodes, rather than parallel transistors.

[image]

Photodiodes are diodes, so this scenario amounts to parallel diodes.

Based on info [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bh8eeb.png), if parallel diodes are fed by different voltages, the common cathode connection will show the higher of the two voltages, as suggested in the question.

Since the diodes are feeding a high-impedance input (as specified in the question), there's little chance of overheating the diode. But that should be validated by checking the datasheet of the optocoupler, compared to calculated current draw of the high-impedance load.

There may be a small amount of leakage between the parallel diodes, depending on the devices used. The HCNR200 has leakage up to 8 nA, which would mean 8 nA flowing from the higher-voltage device into the output of the lower voltage device. The datasheet doesn't mention any ill effects from that.

[image]

However, this device, to be used as intended, requires two external amplifiers, to achieve linearity.

[image]

This [Digikey article](https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/linear-optical-isolation-for-safe-sensor-operation) provides a great explanation for how this error correction works.

So, contrary to @TimWilliams comment, we're not discussing parallel diodes; we're discussing parallel amplifiers. In the datasheet example, we'd be connecting the outputs of multiple A2's in parallel.

In that case, there's the possibility of temperature deviation between the amplifiers. Temperature deviation *isn't* actually relevant to the question, since reverse-leakage can happen *whether or not* there's temperature deviation between the amplifiers (although the *amount* of leakage might be affected by temperature drift). But, since you've gone to the trouble of using a temperature-compensated optocoupler, i'll assume you'll also use temperature-compensated op amps.

Matched components, as mentioned in a comment by @TimWilliams, is also not relevant to reverse leakage, as reverse leakage can happen *whether or not* the amplifiers are matched (although the *amount* of leakage might be affected by mismatch).

The servo-control of the optocoupler *might* correct for nonlinearities, drift, and mismatch in the amplifiers. LittelFuse informed me

> Our linear Optocoupler devices do not require any precision opamps. LM358 (as shown in [AN-107](https://www.littelfuse.com/media?resourcetype=application-notes&itemid=9b0f7d26-6022-4cee-b739-70ba2402b986&filename=an-107) on page 7). Other opamps including the LM324 and the LT1366 rail-to-rail opamp are also mentioned in AN-107 and discussed.

The concern with parallel op amps is that the higher-voltage output could feed current into the output of the lower-voltage output.

This problem can be rectified (literally) with an additional series diode on the output of each amplifier, as suggested in the question. In that case, we're no longer talking about parallel amplifiers -- we're back to parallel diodes. That ensures your output will be the highest voltage present at the parallel optocouplers.

This brings back the diode reverse-leakage issue. Any leakage would feed into the amplifier output of the lower-voltage optocoupler.

I don't know if reverse leakage is proportional to load current. But, if so, then a very low-current load, as mentioned in the question, would minimize reverse leakage in the diodes.

Max amount of leakage would be determined by your choice of series output diode. You may choose eg. [nexperia BAS716](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BAS716.pdf) Low-leakage diode, with leakage of 0.2 nA.

Comment: I can't see why you're considering a mixer when you want to detect the maximum of the various inputs.

Comment: Two unknowns in my answer: 1) Is reverse leakage in the series output diodes proportional to load current? 2) Does the servo-control of the optocoupler correct for nonlinearities, drift, and mismatch in the amplifiers? I'm guessing the answer is 'yes' to all, except for drift. If both op amps drift in the same direction, by roughly the same amount, then i'm guessing the output will also drift in that direction by the average amount.